# Gulp - watchtask start even if I open a file

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

I made a watch task in gulp and everything works fine, but I want to run the task only if I save one of the watched files (in atom for example). Right now the task starts too, when I open one of these files. Should it be like this?

my code:

```
gulp.task('dev', ['htmlhint','jshint','sass-dev', 'uglifycss', 'libs-prod', 'init-prod', 'copy', 'openInBrowser']);

gulp.task('watch',['dev'], function() {
    gulp.watch('/src/html/*.html', ['dev']);
    gulp.watch('/src/scss/**/*.scss', ['dev']);
    gulp.watch(['/src/js/lang/*.js', '/src/js/*.js'], ['dev']);
});
```

I ask because I want to add a task for uploading my files to a ftpserver and that would be quite annoying if it starts every time I just open a file..

Comment: So "dev" task runs initially - as it should - and then runs again every time you just open a file?  What dev program are you using?

Comment: I use atom for dev. Yes, watch task is running again when I open a watched file..

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code you showed.  Although there is a lot of overkill, such as rerunning the sass-dev task whenever you modify the js or html, for example.  Could you have Atom saving the previous tab file that you are leaving when you open another file?

Comment: Some editors, like VSCode - based on Atom, have an option to autosave a file on a tab or window focus change.  Perhaps you have something like that enabled.